# possible combinations get a targetTotal counting itself as a case

Tags: javascript

Trying to count possible combinations to get a `targetTotal`. Using `powerSet` returns the sum without adding itself. E.g `[1,2,3,5]` returns `[3+1]` for a `targetSum` of `4`, whereas I expect to get `[1+1+1+1]`, `[2+2]`, `[3+1]`.

Do you have any ideas how I could make it count itself first as a case?

```
function powerset(arr) {
var ps = [[]];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
        ps.push(ps[j].concat(arr[i]));
    }
}
return ps;
}

function sum(arr) {
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    total += arr[i];
return total
}

function findSums(numbers, targetSum) {
var sumSets = [];
var numberSets = powerset(numbers);
for (var i=0; i < numberSets.length; i++) {
    var numberSet = numberSets[i]; 
    if (sum(numberSet) == targetSum)
        sumSets.push(numberSet);
}
return sumSets;
}
```

Example invocation:

```
findSums([1,2,3,4,5],6); [[2,3], [1,4], [5], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3]]
```